# Why does Lucene QueryParser needs an Analyzer

Tags: lucene, analyzer, query-parser

I'm new to Lucene and trying to parse a raw string into a `Query` using the `QueryParser`.

I was wondering, why is the `QueryParser.Parse()` method needs an Analyzer parameter at all?

If analyzing is something that has to do with querying, then an `Analyzer` should be specified when dealing with regular `Query` objects as well (`TermQuery`, `BooleanQuery` etc), and if not, why is `QueryParser` requires it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When indexing, Lucene divides the text into atomic units (tokens). During this phase many things can happen (e.g. lowercasing, stemming, removal of stopwords, etc.). The end result is a term.

Then, when you query, Lucene applies exactly the same algorithm to the query so it can match term with a term.

Q: Why doesn't `TermQuery` require analyzer?
A: `QueryParser` object parses query string and produces `TermQuery` (can also produce other types of queries, e.g. `PhraseQuery`). `TermQuery` already contains terms in the same shape as they are in the index. If you (as a programmer) are absolutely sure what you doing, you can create a `TermQuery` yourself -- but this assumes you know the exact sequence of query parsing and you know how terms look like in the index.

Q: Why doesn't `BooleanQuery` require analyzer?
A: `BooleanQuery` just joins other queries using operators (AND/OR/MUST/SHOULD, etc.). It's not really useful itself without any other queries.

This is a **very** simplified answer. I highly recommend reading [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) book; it contains the theory based on which Lucene (and other similar frameworks) is written. This book is available online for free.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't explain why specifying the analyzer is only required when parsing string to query and not always when querying.

Comment: Edited my answer, let me know if it's not clear enough or misses anything.