# Searching for Terms with whitespace using Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, whitespace

I'm trying to use Lucene to add a search feature but can't seem to get an index to work with significant whitespace. I've got the following test case setup:

```
RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory();
KeywordAnalyzer analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("content", "Bill Evans", Field.Store.NO));
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.close();

IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("content", analyzer);
parser.setSplitOnWhitespace(false);
Query query = parser.parse("Bill E");

TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 1);
assertTrue(docs.totalHits > 0);
```

I'm using Lucene 6.6.0 and from what I understand the `KeywordAnalyzer` is what I'm looking for:

> "Tokenizes" the entire stream as a single token. This is useful for data like zip codes, ids, and some product names.

But I can't seem to get any matching documents that contain whitespace.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you index, you have a single document with a single field and with a single term with value - `Bill Evans`

When you are going to search, `TermQuery` produced by `QueryParser` tries to search with term value - `Bill E` and that term obviously doesn't exist in index so you get zero hits.

if you replace your search string with - `Bill Evans` , you will get results.

Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226337/why-does-lucene-queryparser-needs-an-analyzer) too

First , you need to separate your indexing and searching concerns. You can only search what is indexed. If you are indexing full texts without breaking into tokens then at search times - you need to produce `WildCardQuery` , `FuzzyQuery` , `PhraseQuery` etc if your input string at search time is different than what in indexed. `TermQuery` searches for exact term values.

My suggestion would to be to store full text value ( without tokens - `StringField` would do that  ) as well as generate additional tokens breaking on space using something like - `SimpleAnalyzer` .

So Something like,

```
doc.add(new TextField("content", "Bill Evans", Field.Store.NO));
doc.add(new StringField("storedcontent", "Bill Evans", Field.Store.YES));
```

Above code with `SimpleAnalyzer` , you will now have terms - `bill` & `evans` 
 ( as well as full text as stored field ) and if you now search with same analyzer , your query would be like - `content:bill content:e` & you will get a result.

All in all - system is working the way you have coded it :)

So understand your requirements first as what you wish to index and what kind of queries you wish to perform on that index.